# How do I make a "command used" counter?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a "This command has been used x amount of times" but I'm struggling a lot. I'm trying to write it to a file.

I've tried stuff such as
`client.commandCount+= 1` but this didn't work. I've been trying to add + 1 to let's variables etc and had no luck.

```
   if (message.content.startsWith("/writenumber")) {
     client.useCount = 0
     fs.writeFile("commandsused.txt", client.useCount += 1, finished)

     function finished(err) {
       console.log("Added.")
     }
   }
```

I expected this to write to the file the current count + 1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Pitto edited the question to include more.

Comment: you are setting use count to 0 every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the count to 0 at every execution.

Is this the issue?

From your question it is not clear if the file is not written at all or if it doesn't contain expected data.

In case the file is written but only contains 0 please try something similar:

```
   if (message.content.startsWith("/writenumber")) {
     console.log("Current value of client.useCount:");
     console.log(client.useCount);
     client.useCount += 1;
     console.log("Updated value of client.useCount:");
     console.log(client.useCount);
     fs.writeFile("commandsused.txt", client.useCount, finished)

     function finished(err) {
       console.log("Added.")
     }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've done a terrible job at explaining this. It DOES write the file but it does not add the +1 on. Using your method, it just stays at 1.

Comment: @Surve I've updated the code, can you please test it and report output? I suspect that this is related to the client object.